# Are these two functions identical? (part II)

Tags: real-analysis

This is a modification to this question:
[Are these two functions identical?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734316/are-these-two-functions-identical)

The modified question:
For all points $x \in  \mathbb{R}$, and for all $h>0$, the neighborhood $(x−h,x+h)$ contains points $c1,c2,c3,c4$ such that $|f(c1)−g(c2)|=|f(c3)−g(c4)|*h$.

Is it true that $f=g$ everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$? If so, why? If not, counterexample?

Comment: How do the counterexamples there or counterexamples similar to those not apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lef $f$ be the Dirichlet function (an indicator function of the rational numbers), $g$ be the zero function. Each interval contains such four points, that all four functions' values are zero and satisfy your equality as $$|0-0|=|0-0|\cdot h$$
alhough the functions are certainly different.